# Formatting the table of contents in a thesis document

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc, ucalgthes1

Sorry for another newbie post. Long-story-short, I'm working in a custom thesis document that does not allow me to use `tocloft`. It has definitions for part, chapter, section, subsection, etc; however, the definition for part creates formatting errors that I've had to solve manually ([my previous question is about this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587648/specifying-parts-and-chapters-while-using-includechapter)). There are two errors in my table of contents I need to fix. Firstly, there is no dotted gap between the title and the page number for `\part{}`, and secondly there is no rule forcing the part title to take a new line in the TOC. See below:

[image: My Table of Contents]

I'm ideally looking for code I can use to overwrite the formatting for the `\part{}` command in the TOC. My class seems to be compatible with the `titletoc` package, if that would work? Thank you for any input or help.

Edit: I would also be happy to suppress the page numbers for Parts, and create a rule that there should be a newline for each Part.

Edit Edit: Currently, I'm using `\dottedcontents{part}[3.8 em]{}{2.3 em}{1 pc}` from the `titletoc` package to get the following formatting. Unfortunately, I can't seem to achieve proper indentation, fontsize or boldface to differentiate parts from chapters.
[image]

Comment: It is a great pity that your document does not allow you to use the `tocloft` package that would enable you to typeset the ToC that you wanted. Any thoughts about contacting the creators of the thesis class?

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm not sure I could contact them even if I needed to, according to the documentation it's been about 30 years since they created it. I'll look into it if I can't fix this in the next month or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in the `thes12.clo` file that produces the problem with `\part`. It can be solved by adding

`\renewcommand{\Huge}{\huge}`

to the preamble.

The output on the Part page and the style of the table of contents (space, fonts, dotted lines) is what the class code does.

I changed the include(s) in your MWE but they not make any difference.

[image: a]

[image: t]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgthes1}  
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom= 1in, left= 1in, right= 1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  
%\usepackage{hyperref}  % commented to avoid link red boxes in TOC for this MWE
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{ulem}  

\renewcommand{\Huge}{\huge} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\title{Towards a Title \\For Stack Exchange}  

\author{Me}  
\thesisyear{2021}  
\thesis{thesis}  
\newcommand{\thesistitle}{Name}  
\monthname{JUNE}  
\dept{Faculty}  
\degree{Degree}  

\providecommand\phantomsection{} %compile with or without hyperref 

\begin{document}  
\makethesistitle  
\pagenumbering{roman}     % resets page counter to one  
\setcounter{page}{2}  

\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\chapter{C0-Abstract} 

\newpage  
\phantomsection  

\chapter{C0-Acknowledgements}

\begin{singlespace}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\tableofcontents  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\listoftables  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\listoffigures  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\clearpage  
\clearpage         
\end{singlespace}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\chapter*{\bf{List of Symbols, Abbreviations and Nomenclature}\hfill}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}  
\listofsymbols  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\clearpage  

\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\part{FIRST}
\chapter{C1-Intro}
\chapter{C1-Method}
\part{SECOND}
\chapter{C2-Result}
\chapter{C2-Conclusions}
\part{THREE}
\chapter{Bibligraphy} 

%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  
%\bibliography{references}  

\end{document}
```

Related with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588326/161015

**UPDATE**

[image: Z]

If you like to have the name and the page number in bold use this code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgthes1}  
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom= 1in, left= 1in, right= 1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  
%\usepackage{hyperref}  % commented to avoid link red boxes in TOC for this MWE
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{ulem}  

\renewcommand{\Huge}{\huge} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\makeatletter   
\def\l@part#1#2{\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{1.25em plus 1pt}  % space above part line
    \begingroup
    \@tempdima 3em         % 
    \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth%     
    \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
    {\bfseries  % set line in  boldface 
        \leavevmode      % 
        #1\hfil \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
    \nobreak%            
    \endgroup}
\makeatother

\title{Towards a Title \\For Stack Exchange}  

\author{Me}  
\thesisyear{2021}  
\thesis{thesis}  
\newcommand{\thesistitle}{Name}  
\monthname{JUNE}  
\dept{Faculty}  
\degree{Degree}  

\providecommand\phantomsection{} %compile with or without hyperref 

\begin{document}  
\makethesistitle  
\pagenumbering{roman}     % resets page counter to one  
\setcounter{page}{2}  

\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\chapter{C0-Abstract} 

\newpage  
\phantomsection  

\chapter{C0-Acknowledgements}

\begin{singlespace}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\tableofcontents  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\listoftables  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\listoffigures  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\clearpage  
\clearpage         
\end{singlespace}  
\newpage  
\phantomsection  
\chapter*{\bf{List of Symbols, Abbreviations and Nomenclature}\hfill}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}  
\listofsymbols  
\pagestyle{plain}  
\clearpage  

\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\part{FIRST}
\chapter{C1-Intro}
\chapter{C1-Method}
\part{SECOND}
\chapter{C2-Result}
\chapter{C2-Conclusions}
\part{THREE}
\chapter{Bibligraphy} 

%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  
%\bibliography{references}  

\end{document}
```

I do not think having dotted lines for parts in the TOC is a good idea when there is gap in between. (and the less ink the better)

Comment: Hi Simon! Thank you for your answer! This resolves the issue on the PART pages (which is why I accepted the answer on the other question), but did not resolve the table of contents problems, which I'm still having some trouble with. The table of contents after using this fix is identical to without it unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation to get the result you first show? I like that format quite a bit. I have found some little workarounds for fixing the table of contents but with my hacky fixes the formatting is functional but ugly. I've been using:

`\dottedcontents{part}[3.8 em]{}{2.3 em}{1 pc}`

Comment: Thank for your feedback. Pleas see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Simon, this works great!!